# Advance filtering of json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am creating a graph generator using d3 to create a graph of student marks against subject
so i have an array

```
var jsonData={
  "_id": "64fef13b9122b9e16aafddab",
  "xie_id": 202201018,
  "name": "Jane",
  "branch": "COMPS",
  "year": 2020,
  "sem": 3,
  "exam_type": "IAT-1",
  "Subject": "DSA",
  "Marks": 72,
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": "64fef13b9122b9e16aafddae",
  "xie_id": 202201019,
  "name": "John",
  "branch": "IT",
  "year": 2021,
  "sem": 1,
  "exam_type": "IAT-1",
  "Subject": "Maths_3",
  "Marks": 45,
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": "64fef13b9122b9e16aafddc9",
  "xie_id": 202201028,
  "name": "Isabella",
  "branch": "IT",
  "year": 2021,
  "sem": 1,
  "exam_type": "IAT-1",
  "Subject": "CG",
  "Marks": 12,
  "__v": 0
}
```

the way  it is supposed to work is that when the array is passsed the branch gets parsed and is shown in a dropdown when the branch is selected the code then filters the years of the branch and shows them on a dropdown when the year is selected the code is supposed to filter the sem which exist for those year and branch from the json array but it does not work and returns an empty array.I dont know whats wrong in my logic.The Branch and Year filter work without any problems . So any help would be appreciated

```
<div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="branch">Branch:</label>
        <select id="branch" value={selectedBranch} onChange={(e) => setSelectedBranch(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="">All Branches</option>
          {branches.map((branch) => (
            <option key={branch} value={branch}>
              {branch}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
```

```
<div>
        <label htmlFor="year">Year:</label>
        <select id="year" value={selectedYear} onChange={(e) => setSelectedYear(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="">All Years</option>
          {years.map((year) => (
            <option key={year} value={year}>
              {year}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
```

```
<div>
        <label htmlFor="semester">Semester:</label>
        <select id="semester" value={selectedSemester} onChange={(e) => setSelectedSemester(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="">All Semesters</option>
          {semesters.length > 0 ? (
            semesters.map((semester) => (
              <option key={semester} value={semester}>
                {semester}
              </option>
            ))
          ) : (
            <option disabled>No semesters found</option>
          )}
        </select>
      </div>
```

Branch filter

```
useEffect(() => {
    const uniqueBranches = [...new Set(jsonData.map((d) => d.branch))];
    setBranches(uniqueBranches);
  }, [jsonData]);
```

Year Filter

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedBranch) {
      const uniqueYears = [...new Set(jsonData.filter((d) => d.branch === selectedBranch).map((d) => d.year))];
      setYears(uniqueYears);
      setSelectedYear('');
      setSelectedSemester('');
      setSelectedName('');
      setSelectedExamType('');
    } else {
      setYears([]);
      setSemesters([]);
      setNames([]);
      setExamTypes([]);
    }
  }, [selectedBranch, jsonData]);
```

Sem Filter

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedYear) {
      const uniqueSemesters = [...new Set(jsonData.filter((d) => d.branch === selectedBranch && d.year === selectedYear).map((d) => d.sem))];
      setSemesters(uniqueSemesters);
      setSelectedSemester('');
      setSelectedName('');
      setSelectedExamType('');
    } else {
      setSemesters([]);
      setNames([]);
      setExamTypes([]);
    }
  }, [selectedYear, selectedBranch, jsonData]);
```

Comment: Too much code shared here, could you try to make your question more concise and focus on just what doesn't work?

Comment: Also, what framework is this?  You've only added the `javascript` tag and your HTML is clearly using some sort of templating framework. Please add the appropriate tags and pair down your code. I am also no clear on what your problem is, it's too much code to sort though for what you describe as an array filtering issue.

Comment: Your array is missing `[]` around it.